# Is there any Legal Issues with Tor in Brazil?

Tags: exit-relays, legal

In Brazil, your ISP, according to the law, must keep a track of the connections you do with your IP address from your network. This track is used to prove that "you" (or someone using your WiFi, or some virus, or someone who infected you with a Trojan, or someone with a laptop in those conditions that used it in your home, but, for our law, "you") did something in your network, when someone breaks the law and there's an IP record of the source.

So, what if someone uses Tor for sharing, e.g., kid's porn, and some file transfer happens by your network's node? Would you be in trouble? Is there any way to avoid that?

Comment: Replying in English to keep the discussion going. In Brazil the law is pretty blind for what actually happens, that's also why you always need to register a document when connecting to a public wifi (CPF required in many cases). I'm no layer, but a few justice documents show that Brazilian laws tend more to neutrality rather than otherwise in the spectrum. [Check here](http://direito-legal.jusbrasil.com.br/noticias/238584592/a-responsabilidade-civil-dos-provedores-de-hospedagem-e-conteudo-de-internet-e-a-protecao-dos-direitos-da-personalidade). One issue is that there they are talking about se

Answer (score 1):

This could perhaps be interpreted as a wider question on whether or not the use of encryption in general is legal in Brazil. If it *is* legal, then surely expecting ISPs, and by extension anyone running a Tor relay, to keep details on their users' IP addresses would be unrealistic.

A good place to start would be http://www.cryptolaw.org/, and the entry for [Brazil](http://www.cryptolaw.org/cls2.htm#br).

Their site states (in the entry for domestic cryptography use):

> There are no controls on crypto use.

(The site contains references to where they've gleaned the information.)

Comment: Yes, the use of encryption is pretty legal. Although, it's mandatory for ISPs to keep the track of IP addresses for 10 years. For users, it's not mandatory to keep a track of whom used your IP address, but in fact you're responsible for everything that your ISP tells that came from your IP. I can't even state if a user stored control would be acceptable by our justice.