# Is TOR legal in Ukraine?

Tags: legal

Is TOR usage legal in **Ukraine**? I mean for legal purposes. Are there any countries where TOR is not legal? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

Questions like this have [come up before](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/9768/is-there-any-legal-issues-with-tor-in-brazil). The more general question would be whether *encryption* is illegal in Ukraine.

The country does have its own set of regulations for the use of cryptography, which do also *seem* to apply to domestic use, as detailed on the [Ukraine](http://www.cryptolaw.org/cls2.htm#ukr) page of the cryptolaw.org site:

> **2. Domestic laws and regulations**
>
> Production, trade and use of cryptography are subject to licensing, according to the Law On
>   Licensing Certain Types of Economic Activity of 1 June 2000. Licenses
>   are issued by the Department of Special Telecommunication Systems and
>   Protection of Information of the Security Service of Ukraine (SBU). A
>   joint order, No. 88/66, of the State Committee for Regulatory Policy
>   and Entrepreneurship and the SBU’s Telecom Department regulates the
>   use of encryption and contains an application form to request a
>   license.

You would have to research further to determine if there are any existing legal precedences - i.e. previous cases - showing how easy the above laws would be to enforce.

With regards as to whether Tor is illegal in other countries: almost certainly in countries where domestic use of encryption is illegal, of which there must be plenty. (Regardless of what the Tor FAQ says... )

Answer (score 1):

TOR is not legal in **Belarus**, Ukraine's neighbor. Belarusian government maintains a list of blocked internet resources. All instruments that could allow users to access these resources are forbidden there.

Answer (score 0):

There's no explicit prohibitions of Tor in any country as far a sI know, **but** there's some law collisions that can make Tor usage illegal, like the [case of Pakistan](https://www.techdirt.com/articles/20110830/02133315734/pakistan-officially-bans-all-encryption-online.shtml), or [Zimbabwe case](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interception_of_Communications_Bill_2006) . In Ukraine - as far as I know - it's legal

Comment: And what about TAILS OS? It is also legal in Ukraine?

Comment: @Next Tails OS = Linux distro. Linux is legal in Ukraine, so Tails too

Comment: Do you use TAILS? Does it really give more anonymity in the Internet?

Comment: @Next no, I'm using my distro I'm about to release soon. TAILS is too raw for me, I didn't liked it]